# Постраничный вывод запроса php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Помогите с таким кодом. Суть в том чтобы брать из базы выборку и постранично в php ее выдавать. Есть код, который работает, когда выборка вся. Когда же я добавляю форму поиска, то страницы он считает верно, но на переходе в другую страницу, переменная сбивается, и у меня пустой экран. Я так понял эту переменную как то надо сохранить при переходе на следующие страницы, но как. Вот сам Код (вверху в Html окно с поиском):

```php
include('adm/connectdb.php');
$num = 8;
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

  $page = $_GET['page'];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `db1` WHERE `name`LIKE \"%$search%\"");
  $posts = mysql_result($result, 0);
  $total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
  $page = intval($page);
  if (empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
  if ($page > $total) $page = $total;
  $start = $page * $num - $num;
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db1` WHERE `name`LIKE \"%$search%\" LIMIT $start, $num");
  while ($postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: очевидно в скрытый инпут выводить значение и потом его при очередном запросе забирать

Comment: Получается в php коде добавить input, в который также передать переменную search?

Comment: Не нужно делать поиск через `$_POST`-переменную, используйте `$_GET`. Кстати, что в переменной `$search`?

Comment: В переменной некий текст, по которому пользователь ищет инфу. Я сменил на $_GET, но теперь у меня совсем ничего не ищет, нужно ли в SQL запросе что-то менять?

Comment: переделал в get запрос, в браузерной строке слово пишется (правда на русском некорректно), но выводит всю выборку, и также вторую и следуюие страницы - пустые

Answer (score 0):

Записывайте условие поиска в сессию

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $search = $_POST['search'];
  $_SESSION['search'] = $search;
} else if (isset($_SESSION['search']))
  $search = $_SESSION['search'];

if (isset($search)) {
  $page = $_GET['page']; 
  .........
```

Когда нужно будет сбросить фильтр выполните

```
unset($_SESSION['search']);
```

Comment: с этим у меня совсем выпало в ошибку
 Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie
причем поискав в интернете уже пересохранил в формат UTF без BOM и убрал все пробелы в коде

Comment: @Сергей `session_start()` должно вызываться до вывода **любой** информации в браузер.

Comment: Спасибо, я вывел php скрипт на самый верх, до html кода, но теперь форма, которая на странице в виде html кода просо не показывается, как с этим быть?

Comment: @Сергей Самое банальное - в скрипте первой строчкой выполнить `session_start()` а все остальное - там где нужно

Comment: Чтот я совсем запутался, я создал пустую страницу, как раз чтобы не теряться в коде, так она и выглядит у меня. Или сначала надо просто строку session start сделать, и тег php закрыть и дальше по списку?
<?php
include ('adm/connectdb.php');
$num = 8;
session_start();
..............
while ( $postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
?>
<form method="post" class="search">
<input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: @Сергей Я уже Вам писал `session_start()` должно вызываться до вывода любой информации в браузер. Все остальное - не важно